# Picturebox text does not always show

Tags: picturebox

I have setup 100 pictureboxes and added a text element using drawstring. I use as loop to update the text at the same time I set the picturebox background color. After loop not all the text get displayed. Some are blank and some show but its intermittent.

```
    Private Sub LoadStepPatternFlash()

    intBank = intSequenceNumber * 100

    For intCounter = 0 To 99

        Dim g As Graphics = PicPixel(intCounter).CreateGraphics()
        PicPixel(intCounter).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(intPatternColorsRed(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)), intPatternColorsGreen(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)), intPatternColorsBlue(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)))

        g.DrawString(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank), New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.White, 1, 1)
        '      PicPixel(intCounter).Refresh()
    Next

End Sub
```

If I put a breakpoint at endsub then F5 (continue) the text shows fine each time. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, I dont draw on the picturebox but I create a bitmap and draw on the bitmap and then post bitmap image to picturebox. All the issues resoleved.

```
    Private Sub LoadStepPatternFlash()


    Dim NG As Graphics
    Dim Color_Background As Color
    Dim Brush_Background As Brush

    Dim LastColorIndicator As Color
    Dim LastColorBrush As Brush

    Dim bmp As Bitmap


    intBank = intSequenceNumber * 100

    If intSequenceNumber > 0 Then
        intLastBank = (intSequenceNumber - 1) * 100
    End If


    For intCounter = 0 To 99

        Dim Pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.White)

        bmp = New Bitmap(Pb_Seg1.Image)     '//Image is white bitmap
        NG = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

        Color_Background = Color.FromArgb(intPatternColorsRed(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)), intPatternColorsGreen(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)), intPatternColorsBlue(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank)))
        Brush_Background = New SolidBrush(Color_Background)
        NG.FillRectangle(Brush_Background, 0, 0, 30, 30)

        LastColorIndicator = Color.FromArgb(intPatternColorsRed(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intLastBank)), intPatternColorsGreen(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intLastBank)), intPatternColorsBlue(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intLastBank)))
        LastColorBrush = New SolidBrush(LastColorIndicator)
        NG.FillRectangle(LastColorBrush, 0, 0, 12, 12)
        NG.DrawRectangle(Pen, 0, 0, 12, 12)
        Pen.Dispose()

        If ShowPixelNumber Then
            NG.DrawString((intCounter + 1), New Font("Arial", 8), Brushes.White, 20, 20)

        End If

        If ShowColorNumber Then
            NG.DrawString(strhexPixelHexValue(intCounter + intBank), New Font("Arial", 8), Brushes.White, 1, 1)
        End If

        PicPixel(intCounter).Image = bmp

    Next

End Sub
```